# How can I edit a question that solicits debate, arguments, etc. when that's the nature of the question?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, closed-questions

MY SE account was banned and I want to improve question to possibly get unbanned. Among these links which casued the ban was [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/170928/needs-management-tool-for-java-files). The question, by nature, is debatable, and thus was closed. Since it was closed within 30 days of the ban, it was put into consideration. Will deleting this post take away further consideration of whether my account can be considered unbanning?

Comment: Chris we migrated this from Meta Stack Overflow to Meta Programmers, for future reference please ask about Programmers specific issues here, MSO is for Stack Overflow and network wide issues.

Comment: @YannisRizos, Allright, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't that your question solicits debate (although it might). In this case, I can't tell *what the heck you're asking!*

You can edit your question and request it be re-opened through a flag; but unless you clean up your question I can see it being deleted very soon.

Your question (as it was originally structured) was not constructive (see: DLL Hell); but as it stands now, I'd still close it as 'Not a real Question'.

Comment: When it was fixed at the point of the state where the title had "DLL Hell" in it, and _IIRC_, **only -1 - it is now at -5.** Probally becuase like what you stated - it is still bad in it's current state. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

> Will deleting this post take away further consideration of whether my account can be considered unbanning?

Deleting a question would have quite the opposite effect, as question ban considers also deleted questions, whenever they are deleted from you, or other users.

What you can do is putting the question in shape, fixing it basing on what [George Stocker](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/16587/george-stocker) said in his answer here.
The alternative is getting up-voted for answering questions asked by other users.

Comment: Thanks clearing that up. I wasn't sure if I should ask about that since it seems all i've done latelty was cause bad posts and didn't want to waste more of ya'lls time... But this was helpfull to know. Thank You!

Answer (score 5):

These are your questions:

[image]

The two in red are deleted, and are also taken into account in the question ban. As you can see *some* of your questions were more than welcome, and some were heavily downvoted, closed and deleted (and lead to the ban). It's clear to me that you are more than capable of writing a good question, and I have no idea how someone who asked [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/167982/web-crawler-for-learning-topics-on-wikipedia) then went and asked [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/170928/1).

Anyway, what you need to do now is:

1. Read our [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly

   A couple of your questions simply don't belong on Programmers. If you want any clarifications on what topics we welcome, you can ask here on Meta or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard).
2. Stop trying to be cute

   While all of us appreciate humour, it doesn't really have a place in your questions or your answers. Questions especially should be as clear and to the point as possible, you are asking the Programmers crowd for free help, answerers should be able to understand what your core question is without much effort.

   A couple of resources that will help you ask better questions in the future (and perhaps improve your existing ones):

   - Matt Gemmell's excellent article [What have you tried?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/revisions/170928/1), and
   - Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) blog post, the canonical guide on asking questions on Stack Overflow (the principles apply on Programmers as well).
3. Contribute some great answers

   Don't rush into answering just to reverse the ban. Find questions that you feel are not sufficiently answered, and give them your best shot. Don't repeat earlier answers, only answer if you have something new to add, back up your answers with solid references and make them as clear as possible.

Although the exact question ban algorithm is kept secret, from a very high level view you seem to be very near the ban threshold, it shouldn't take a lot of effort to reverse it. Our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard) may feel deserted at times, but if you have *anything* to ask, just ask, someone will respond sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate the encouragement. I will definently check out those resources on how to write good questions ane what belongs where, and will start to answer some peoples questions.